# RecoveryServicesManagementAgent Stopped (Delayed Start)

Tags: azure

I am receiving the following message from the nightly backup:
'RecoveryServicesManagementAgent    Stopped  (Delayed Start)'

What is causing it and how do I fix it?

I have Windows Server 2012 R2. 
Thanks

Comment: It's being caused by the recovery services management agent stopping, as to why, I have no idea. Look in your event logs and see what error messages are present, do some actual debugging.

Comment: I think we need to collect the logs of this error, so we can find out what happened, and what caused it. At times the process “RecoveryServicesManagementAgent” would have been struck or shutdown, if the process is not running, browse the list of services from control panel, **start** or **restart** "Azure Recovery Services Management Agent", and rerun the backup job.
For further information, browse the logs at "Azure backup agent installation folder"\Microsoft Azure Recovery Services Agent\Temp\GatewayProvider*.